# Treinamento Rede Neural MLP

Tags: inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma rede neural para reconhecimento de 5 figuras geométricas: círculo, estrela, pentágono, quadrado e triângulo. A rede é do tipo MLP com 1 camada oculta(10 neurônios), a camada de entrada possui 400 neurônios, um para cada pixel da imagem com a figura geométrica e a camada de saída possui 1 neurônio, o qual deve atingir um valor para cada figura: 0.0 - Círculo, 0.25 - Estrela, 0.5 - Pentágono, 0.75 - Quadrado, 1.0 - Triângulo. O método de aprendizado é de backpropagation.

Os dados de entrada são normalizados em 0 e 1; 1 no caso para a cor branca e 0 para cor preta, pois as imagens são do tipo bitmap monocromático.

Para o treinamento utiliza-se 27 padrões de cada tipo mencionado acima, desenhados em uma matriz de 20x20 px, resultando nos 400 neurônios da camada de entrada. Para a validação da rede, que é feita em cada época de treinamento estão dispostas 18 padrões de cada tipo.

O problema está no treinamento, onde a rede de fato converge para um erro mínimo, porém a mesma fica muito instável, conforme o gráfico:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outros parâmetros da rede:

- Taxa de aprendizado: 0.1
- Momentum: 0.8
- Neurônios camada oculta: 10

Já tentei alterar os 3 parâmetros acima, porém sem sucesso, ou a rede fica mais instável, ou demora um longo tempo para começar a diminuir o erro. Na verificação das imagens a rede reconhece os padrões, porém eu gostaria de realizar uma parada antecipada baseada em validação cruzada para garantir a generalização da mesma, mas para isso necessita de valores mais sólidos do que os apresentados no gráfico. Desde já obrigado !

Para adequar a rede a situação de classificação, adicionei mais quatro neurônios na camada de saída, totalizando cinco neurônios, sendo cada um ativado para um padrão de figura, e o resultado das linhas de erro foi o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Existe a possibilidade de eu melhorar mais um pouco?

Comment: Eduardo, a sua rede neural é de `classificação`, para melhores resultados você deveria ter 5 neurônios na camada de saída. Utilizar um único neurônio e basear o resultado na sua intensidade seria trabalho para rede de `regressão`, não é o seu caso, um pentágono (0.5) não é metade circulo (0.0), metade triângulo (1.0).

Comment: Ok, vou fazer essa mudança

Comment: Alterei a camada de saída, resultado nos gráficos acima